# Под какие архитектуры необходимо делать release apk?

Tags: android, react-native

У меня вопрос, связанный с release`ом android приложения.

Когда я запускаю команду `./gradlew app:assembleRelease`,  я получаю следующие apk, как на скрине.

[image: варианты apk в зависимости от архитектуры]

Далее я беру версию universal и кладу ее в ruStore и отдаю заинтересованным лицам.

Вопрос:

Что будет, если я буду использовать только версию `arm64-v8a`, в ruStore в том числе, и полностью откажусь от других версий в том числе от версии `universal`?

Просто я вижу что на моем телефоне, эмуляторе и на еще нескольких устройствах используется только `arm64-v8a`.

Как мне известно в Play Market для этого есть удобная возможность ввиде aab файлов, но в ruStore насколько я знаю такого нет, и файлы я вижу различаются в 3 раза по размеру, если в этом надобности нет, хочется использовать меньшего размера apk.

Любые комментарии будут полезны, так как каких-либо знаний android разработки у меня нет, разработку делаю на react-native

Comment: ну чуваки отъедут с 32 битами.
есть интересная ситуация, когда пользователь поставит эмулятор на старый компьютер 32 бит и если он сможет сэмулировать 64 бит на эмуляторе, то у него запустится. 

ставите virtual box и тестите, можно кстати поставить на эмулятор 64 бит систему, на нее 64 бит эмулятор и запустить 64 бит приложение и все это на 32 битной системе, потому что он все равно из песочницы не выйдет.

Comment: а интересно этих чуваков на 32 битах насколько много?)) Как бы это узнать?

Comment: важно не количество, а важно понадобится ли человеку с 32 битами ваше приложение.

Comment: если это просто todolist, то конечно его лучше делать на все платформы, но если это крупный проект, то нужно при том как вы заливаете приложение ограничить его скачивание на 32 бит устройства, то есть playmarket его даже не покажет в поиске, если вы попытаетесь найти на устройстве 32 бит.

Comment: в Play Market все предсказуемо, там я отдаю файл aab и далее play market курирует что и кому отдавать. В моем случае приложение закачивается в ruStore, там грузить можно только apk файлы, и теперь не могу понять стоит ли делать сборку включая 32 или таких пользователей настолько мало, что ими можно пренебречь

Comment: arm64-v8a достаточно в наше время.

Comment: Понял, попробую тогда, спасибо вам за ваши советы

Comment: Теперь можно публиковать AAB в RuStore
https://www.rustore.ru/help/developers/publishing-and-verifying-apps/app-publication/upload-aab/

Comment: @OlegA благодарю, буду знать, как появится время, наверное, перейду с apk на aab.